# IIS Inbound Rules Conflicting

Tags: iis, arr

Using the IIS Application Resource Routing (ARR), we have 2 Inbound Rules that seem to be conflicting. We have a few existing IIS Inbound Rules. When we add a new rule it seems to conflict with just one of the existing rules. When both rules are enabled, the new rule doesn't work.

- We have moved the new rule to the top of the rules list.
- We have set "Stop processing of subsequent rules" on this rule. The
  issue persists.

**New Rule:**
*Requested URL:* Matches the Pattern
*Using:* RegEx
*Pattern:* content/?(.*)
*Ingore Case:* Yes
*Conditions:* None
*Server Variables:* None
*Action Type:* Rewrite
*Rewrite URL:* [https://www.example.com/{R:1}](https://www.example.com/%7BR:1%7D)
*Append query string:* Yes
*Log rewritten URL:* No
*Stop processing subsequent rules:* Yes

**Old Rule:**
*Requested URL:* Matches the Pattern
*Using:* RegEx
*Pattern:* ^assets/v/(.*)/(.*)/(css|images|fonts|less)/(.*)$
*Ingore Case:* Yes
*Conditions:* None
*Server Variables:* None
*Action Type:* Rewrite
*Rewrite URL:* ./assets/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:4}?v={R:1}
*Append query string:* Yes
*Log rewritten URL:* No
*Stop processing subsequent rules:* Yes

When the Old Rule is enabled, the new re

IMO:

- the regex in these 2 rules keeps these rules exclusive
- the new rule being 'highest' in the rules list should ensure that it runs.
- The "Stop processing subsequent rules" option being checked should stop after the 1st rule.

Any advice or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Usually people open up `applicationHost.config` and copy/paste the rewrite rules in XML format to their questions. Besides, FRT can help you troubleshoot on your own, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules